# In R Specify any number

Tags: r, numbers

This might be simple, but can't find this anywhere.

```
w <- function(finaltable) {
  if (tail(names(finaltable),1) == c("carried##")) {
    (ncol(finaltable)-2)
  } else {
    (ncol(finaltable)-1)
  }
}
```

Where the two ## signs are, I want to specify any number combo.

Comment: PLease write what you want to acomplish. As it stands, your question is quite unclear. Do you want to return those `ncol(finatable)`? Do you want to alter the input object? what do you want to do? Quoting from [Help Center: "How to ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): *"take a deep breath and read through it from start to finish. Pretend you're seeing it for the first time: does it make sense?"*

Comment: @ it is quite clear Barranka, in my code where the ## are, I want to specify any number.

Comment: @also, dont know why you down voted -3? your corrected based on style and doesnt not deserved down vote of -3

Comment: that -3 means that three users down-voted you, not just one. Assume that I (or any of us) don't know what you are typing or what you are seeing on your R console. Make (at least) a general description of your problem, so you can get a suitable answer. If all you need is to specify that those `##` characters should be placeholders for digits, and everything else works just fine, then take a look to [Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and ["Regular Expressions in R"](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html)

Comment: Do you want to specify the numbers or do you only want to check if there IS any combination of two numbers?

Comment: Well the Carried is a column name, after that there is a series of numbers. I just want to find the last column name as carried with any number combo

Comment: Chad you might think it's clear but the down votes and all of us are telling you - it is not clear. It's a bad question because we don't know what you're asking. We don't have the rest of your code or your overall goal in front of us. All we have is what you wrote and it's not enough to tell us what you want.

Comment: @ everyone, OK I will do my very best to write much better questions. My apologies to everyone

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, replace `if (tail(names(finaltable),1) == c("carried##"))` with `if grepl("^carried(0|[1-9][0-9]*)", tail(names(finaltable),1))`. See if this is what you want.

Comment: @Vlo, this is what I want. I want R to know I want column "carried with any number at the end of finaltable. However, this keeps throwing errors saying the syntax is written wrong. I think () maybe in wrong spot.

Comment: Make your question hole. People will not read all the comments to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can create a sequence of numbers with seq and after that concatenate all in a for loop

```
seq <- seq(1,100)

for(element in seq):
{
  w <- function(finaltable) {
    if (tail(names(finaltable),1) == c("carried", as.character(element))) {
      (ncol(finaltable)-2)
    } else {
      (ncol(finaltable)-1)
    }
  }
}
```

you can use the arguments of seq if you want a particular sequence

```
Arguments

... 
arguments passed to or from methods.

from, to    
the starting and (maximal) end values of the sequence. Of length 1 unless just from is supplied as an unnamed argument.

by  
number: increment of the sequence.

length.out  
desired length of the sequence. A non-negative number, which for seq and seq.int will be rounded up if fractional.

along.with  
take the length from the length of this argument.
```

Comment: well your code helped me indirectly. I didnt know that numbers with characters were treated as characters. Since this is true, I can always do this and get my answer in a robust way w<- function(finaltable){if (nchar(tail(names(finaltable),1) >= nchar(c("carried")))) {(ncol(finaltable)-2)} else (ncol(finaltable)-1)};

Comment: In that way your code is more readable. If my answer was useful (indirectly) please voted it up!

Comment: actually now my else part of loop isnt working. Any ideas? the syntax should be right

Comment: also, the other column character length is 6, so in the function since 6 isnt greater than 7 it should go to else part of code

Comment: Please give me a example of your input to test the function

Comment: I have colnames (digit, dead, carried). I want the digit column. Depending on the day I will have tail(names(finaltable),1 = carried or dead. If carried, I need to subtract two columns, if dead then one column. However, I have several columns named dead or carried that are associated with number. However, the max dead will be is dead99. Thus I have a max of 6 characters.

Comment: Maybe is a better idea to open another thread with all those details and post your code  with a sample of finaltable as well. Do you want to suppress columns of finaltable on the go?